# Is this Java code correct?

Tags: java, loops, iterator

I am having a discussion (read argument!) with one of my colleagues. I maintain that this code is very wrong but he thinks there is nothing wrong with it:

```
for (Iterator<String> iter = collectionOfStrings.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
   String item = iter.next();
   ...
}
```

I maintain that this code is wrong because there is a duplication of looping. Either use Iterator or use a For loop but there is no need to use them both at the same time.

I would re-write the code as follows:

```
Iterator<String> iter = collectionOfStrings.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
   String item = iter.next();
   ...
}
```

What do you think?

Comment: A 'for' loop is just a syntactic shorthand for a 'while' loop anyway. I don't see the point of arguing ....

Comment: A `while` is a loop too!

Comment: Just test it, but seems correct.

Comment: No loops are double in there. While a while loop would be sufficient there is no reason not to use a for loop.

Comment: To me the only difference look like one between a `for` loop and a `while` loop

Comment: The easiest and best should read `for(String item : collectionOfStrings)`, right?

Comment: The for loop example has one advantage: It keeps the scope of the created variables small. In the while example `iter` is visible outside the loop.

Comment: @TimButhe I don't understand why your simplified 'for' loop isn't everyone's answer.

Comment: Tim, if you need to delete the stuff in the collection, the Iterator is preferred, not the : syntax.

Comment: @rcook I don't get it either.

Comment: @tristan2468: If you want to remove stuff, iterator _is_ in fact your only option. Otherwise you'll get ConcurrentModificationExceptions, so 'preferred' is a little understated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Neither code is not "wrong", in the sense that both do what is expected. The second code, although equivalent, pollutes the local variables, because `iter` remains defined after the loop ends.

Answer (score 5):

Both of your examples are syntactically correct.  One advantage of putting the declaration in the for loop is that the variable is released after the code block ends, whereas the iterator persists after the while loop ends

Answer (score 5):

The second is good.

The first is slightly better. It limits the loop variable's scope.

But since Java 1.5, the foreach loop can sometimes be more elegant than either:

```
for ( String item : collectionOfStrings ) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually it's the same. For is just a variation of while, or while is just a variation of for, however you like to put it. You can write a for

```
for (init;cond;incr){
...
}
```

like this

```
init
while(cond){
....
incr
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your colleague is right. The first code, with the `for` loop, should run just fine.

In fact, `while` is also a loop, so both your code and his contains one loop and iterator.